# What is the opposite of the ending "-cide" (as in "suicide", "pesticide")?

Tags: antonyms, suffixes, compounds

I'm looking for the antonym of *-cide* (as in *suicide, pesticide*, etc.). Essentially the ending to words that would mean "to create or embrace".

Answer (score 6):

The suffix [‑genesis](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/-genesis) can be added to connote *creation*. Wiktionary has a list of [words ending in *‑genesis*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:English_words_suffixed_with_-genesis).

Answer (score 4):

In the biomedical field, we add the adjective suffix */-genic/* and the noun suffix */-genesis/* to words to indicate creation, e.g., *oncogenic/oncogenesis, tumorigenic/tumorigenesis*, etc.

Answer (score 1):

"To embrace" may be handled with the suffix "-philia" or "-philic", which means "attracted to".